# Heroku returning 404 but no errors on logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment

Currently I'm getting an error when going to my heroku application, but when I jump into the logs it's not returning any errors whatsoever.

This is what it returns.

```
2015-04-07T00:06:07.664850+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=popcorn.herokuapp.com request_id=d9e5961e-b819-4c5b-b979-b57db7dbb570 fwd="90.200.53.244" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=190ms status=500 bytes=1754
2015-04-07T00:06:08.060105+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=popcorn.herokuapp.com request_id=f5c27031-9e43-4d77-83b8-52337a3084f6 fwd="90.200.53.244" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=14ms status=404 bytes=1829
2015-04-07T00:08:09.761488+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=popcorn.herokuapp.com request_id=42778326-e39a-41e6-a5d2-428ad5eba96f fwd="90.200.53.244" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=35ms status=500 bytes=1754
```

Routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  root "posts#index"
  resources :posts

  resources :categories do
    resources :posts
  end

  get 'tags/:tag', to: 'posts#index', as: :tag
end
```

Any help would be brilliant!

Thanks

Comment: You usually get a 404 when a route is not available too. Odds are that you would not have the root route set to any controller action. Also, I would suggest increasing the `log_level` to `debug` in your `config/production.rb` file and commit, redeploy to heroku.

Comment: @Vineeth I've added my routes.rb to the question.

Comment: Any help would be brilliant :)

Comment: I think you would have already done this but still, did you run `heroku run rake db:migrate` ?

Comment: Ah yes... Completely forgot about that step! Thanks. Whack it as an answer and I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are using Heroku, I hope you have not forgotten to run the migrations on the app.

`heroku run rake db:migrate`